# Debug application without recompile

Tags: delphi

In an earlier version of delphi (2007/2009) I found a way to debug the application without recompiling.

But I can't find it in XE5:(

I often find my self in need of restart debugging to debug a condition that only appears on application load.

So avoiding an unnecessary compile would be a great time saver.

Best regards
Ove B-)

Comment: Your question is not clear. please provide more information and be clear...

Comment: Isnt that what the Build process is for?

Comment: Once the app is terminated, can't you just Run (F9) it?  If it recompiles every single time you run, something is very odd...

Comment: It is possible that something goes wrong in the compile process and application recompiles when it is not needed, but the question in its current form is very unclear. Voted to close.

Comment: Delphi will only recompile if something in the code changed since the last time it was compiled. You can restart debugging without a recompile by just hitting F9, as long as you've not changed anything between runs.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you can debug an application without having delphi trying to recompile it by following these steps:

1. launch the application outside of the debugger (with "run without debugging" or by executing it from windows)
2. attach the debugger to the already running instance you just created by using the delphi menu item "Run->Attach to process..."

Edit: a little error i made: you actually have to launch your program from windows: using the "Run without debugging" option from the IDE will make delphi try to recompile the project.